# Why does GCC pad this bit-field?

Tags: c, struct, padding, atomic, compare-and-swap

Program is in C using std=c99, this is on a 64-bit machine.

```
struct epochs {
    volatile unsigned int epoch    : 1;
    volatile unsigned int pulse    : 1;
    volatile unsigned int active0  : 7;
    volatile unsigned int active1  : 7;
    volatile unsigned int counter0 : 24; 
    volatile unsigned int counter1 : 24; 
};
```

when I check sizeof(epochs) it gives me 12.

I can tell gcc not to pad it by adding __attribute((packed)); so I can work around it. However I would really like to know why 4 bytes are added to pad this 64-bit structure?

The main thing here is that this structure NEEDS to be 64 bits because it is updated all at once in 64-bit atomic swap operations, which of course will not work on a 12-byte value.

Comment: Generally bitfields are allowed to be padded for performence, my best guess, is that the compiler has added padding between your data members, to ensure they are aligned on byte boundaries. Adding the packed attribute will indeed tell the compiler not to add padding for performance.

Comment: Don't use bitfields if you want portable/reproducible behaviour.

Comment: `struct epochs { unsigned int counter0 : 24, pulse : 1, active0 : 7, counter1 : 24, epoch : 1, active1 : 7; };` is 8 bytes on my linux, solaris, and aix. (incidentally, why were they all `volatile`?)

Comment: They are all volatile because different threads may be updating them. Atomic operations take care of making write safe, but volatile is in place to prevent the program from assuming they are unchanged when I need to read from them.

Comment: @Exodist `volatile` does not provide those semantics (atomic operations do, though)

Comment: @Cubbi changing the order of the fields worked, and thanks to the answer provided by ouah below I now understand why. I am considering just making the first 4 fields uint8_t, and the counters uint16_t, I am just not sure if 16-bits is enough for the counters, which is why I want to be able to use the bitfield form if I should find 16-bit counters to be too small.

Comment: @Cubbi I thought volatile was to tell the compiler not to optimize away a read of the variable because it may have changed because of something other than the current program (or in my case thread). My writes are all atomic, but my reads are normal reads (is there an atomic read built-in?) so I want to make sure the compiler does not assume the value is unchanged.

Comment: @Exodist there are [atomic loads in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#_005f_005fatomic-Builtins) which largerly follow the C11/C++11 model.

Comment: ah, this is a different list of atomic builtins from what I am used to, The ones I was looking at are http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
volatile unsigned int epoch    : 1;
volatile unsigned int pulse    : 1;
volatile unsigned int active0  : 7;
volatile unsigned int active1  : 7;
```

^ 32-bit (4 bytes)

```
volatile unsigned int counter0 : 24;
```

^ 32-bit (4 bytes)

```
volatile unsigned int counter1 : 24;
```

^ 32-bit (4 bytes)

So 4 bytes more.

C says :

> (C99, 6.7.2.1p10) "If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit"

There is not enough space to put 24-bit (`counter0`) more in a 32-bit unit (likely the size of `unsigned int` in your system) that already holds 16-bit (`epoch`, `pulse`, `active0`, `active1`).

You can use `uin64_t` instead of using `unsigned int` to pack your bit-fields in a 64-bit unit but it is implementation-defined whether your system supports it or not.

> (C99, 6.7.2.1p4) "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, **or some other implementation-defined type**."

Comment: I think this would be clearer if it noted that the first four fields use 16 bits and then explicitly said that putting the next 24 bits immediately after them would cross a 32-bit boundary. And that GCC likely avoids this because accessing a bit-field that cross a boundary would require two load instructions (depending on target processor) and additional bit-manipulation instructions to combine the loaded values. And storing across a boundary would be even worse. So 32-bit units are preferred for bit-field allocation.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I needed. Arranging my fields based on a 32-bit alignment also means I can avoid padding: counter0, epoch, active0, counter1, pulse, active1.  This makes it stick at 64-bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if i use #pragma pack(), i am getting size of the structure is 8 bytes (not 12 bytes). Here how the memory allocation is happening?

Comment: @EswaranPandi: The six fields in the example in this answer require 1+1+7+7+24+24 = 64 bits, which is eight 8-bit bytes. If, when you request packing, your compiler puts them in eight bytes, then it is clear they are packed into bytes with no padding. However, the compiler may organize the fields in bytes or in, for example, 32-bit words, and it may order the fields from low bits of the unit to high bits or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

While some older compilers used to regard `int foo:3;` as synonymous with e.g. `long foo:3`, or `short foo:3`, and simply place `foo` in whatever manner was convenient, the present C standard specifies that each bit field must fit entirely within a storage unit of the appropriate size.  I have no idea what the rationale was for that specification, since the way bit fields are specified remains too vague to allow their use in portable code, but sometimes makes it impossible to pack things optimally.  For example, the only way a 24-bit value could be stored efficiently within a structure would be to either have a machine which on a machine which supports 32-bit integers, or else have a 8 bits of data which could be placed adjacent to the 24-bit value (preceding or following) so as to "fill out" a 32-bit word.

Fortunately, in your particular case, it's possible to avoid the inefficiency by rearranging your fields.  It may also be possible to avoid the inefficiency by changing the declared type of each field to `unsigned long long` if your compiler supports bitfields using such a type [in that case, bit fields would be allowed to straddle 32-bit boundaries provided they didn't straddle a 64-bit boundary].